# mirror/backup of github repository with metadata

Tags: backup, git, github

(How) would it be possible to make a full backup/mirror of a github repository, including

- all branches and tags (with full history)
- all (open) pull requests
- all premissions/access restrictions
- configured integrations
- deploy keys
- implemented github actions

Preferrably this would be

- done on a self-hosted git server.
- implemented to synchronize automatically (based on some trigger)

So far I have only found out how to make a backup/mirror of

- all branches and tags (with full history) - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578270/fully-backup-a-git-repo

but this would still be lacking all the metadata (actions and whatnot).